# How to change locale using EasyLocalization without context

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, clean-architecture

I am using `EasyLocalization` in my Flutter app and trying to change the locale when the user selects a different language on the setting page of my app.

I can achieve it using:

`EasyLocalization.of(context)?.setLocale(myLocale);`

It works great this way.

The thing is I am developing with BLoC and Clean Architecture, and want to keep my presentation layer clean of any business logic. I want to add the local change to my domain layer instead of the presentation layer.

But `EasyLocalization` requires context in order to change the local.

What would be the best way to change my locale in my domain layer, when I don't have access to the current context?

Answer (score 0):

The common pattern to this problem is the adapter pattern:

- define an interface in your domain layer
- add an implementation to presentation layer which wraps Easy localization and implements that interface
- inject the context into the implementation in your main module
- inject your implementation through the interface into your domain layer

#### Example

(pseudo code)

```cs
// defined in the domain layer
interface ILocalization {
    void SetLocale(string locale);
}

// defined in presentation layer
class LocatizationAdapter : ILocalization {
    private IContext myContext;
    public LocalizationAdapter(IContext context) {
        myContext = context;
    }
    void SetLocale(string locale) {
        EasyLocalization.of(myContext)?.setLocale(locale);
    }
}

// some domain layer class
class DomainService {
    public DomaainService(ILocalization localization) {
    }
}

// the 'main' component (where the app is composed
new DomainService(new LocalizationAdapter(context));
```

This way you can change locale in your domain layer without unwanted dependencies.

Comment: Didn't really understand what you mean. Can you please give some example?

Comment: i have added an example in pseudo code